# Encode/Decode a given Object with specific parameters

Tags: java, generics, encoding, decoding

I have a class with 10s of parameters. I want to encode and decode (back to) this class with limited number of parameters (let's say 3). It means, I am not worried if other parameters change. Assume those keys to be primary keys of the table and we are only concerned about them.

I can obviously use Base64 encoding/decoding to do the final job but handing different object types among those parameters was coming out to be multiple lines of code (with type checks).

One better thing I can think of it using JSON parsing to convert objects first to a JSON then use the encoding but that will again need specifically choosing the parameters. What could be the best way to perform this?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "with limited number of parameters". Do you mean that the class has 10s of fields, but you only want to encode 3 of them, and don't care if the other fields are all wrong when you decode?